# phpize won't work on Mac OS X Lion

Tags: php, macos, xdebug, pecl

I try to install xdebug but I get the follow error message about 'phpize'.
How can I fix this thing?

```
leny:~ nick$ sudo pecl install xdebug
Password:
downloading xdebug-2.1.2.tgz ...
Starting to download xdebug-2.1.2.tgz (304,229 bytes)
............done: 304,229 bytes
66 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20090626
Zend Module Api No:      20090626
Zend Extension Api No:   220090626
Cannot find autoconf. Please check your autoconf installation and the
$PHP_AUTOCONF environment variable. Then, rerun this script.

ERROR: `phpize' failed
```

Comment: I have also run into this problem.  I installed autoconf, and added it into the path in my bash profile, but still get this message. Not sure installing autoconf has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

"Cannot find autoconf" - Install autoconf and retry.

`sudo port install autoconf` but you need Xcode and MacPorts as far as I know.

Comment: Thank u for the fast response. I am a noon in this area, but how do I install autoconf? Thank you!

Answer (score 87):

You can also install autoconf through homebrew. Just run

```
brew install autoconf
```

And all will work

Comment: Got permission errors from this.  Needed to first do: *sudo chown -R yourusername /usr/local* then: *sudo chmod -R u+w /usr/local* and finally: *brew link autoconf*

Answer (score 1):

For me, I had not agreed to the Xcode license :-

```
$ sudo /usr/bin/m4 --version


You have not agreed to the Xcode license agreements. You must agree to both license agreements below in order to use Xcode.

Hit the Enter key to view the license agreements at '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/License.rtf'

IMPORTANT: BY USING THIS SOFTWARE, YOU ARE AGREEING TO BE BOUND BY THE FOLLOWING APPLE TERMS:
```