# Mountain Lion php pear and pecl

Tags: php, pear, osx-mountain-lion, pecl

I've upgraded to Mountain Lion and installed php5.4 which took a bit of tweaking [Mountain Lion change php location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11913850/mountain-lion-change-php-location/)

My next issue is if I run `pear -v` or `pecl -v` these return

```
Could not open input file: /usr/lib/php/pear/pearcmd.php

Could not open input file: /usr/lib/php/pear/peclcmd.php
```

Do I need to change pear and pecl to point to my new php which is installed in /usr/local/php5/bin/

If so how do I do this and will I lose all of my previously installed extensions such as phpunit?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I sorted this by installing pear again. After downloading go-pear.phar then running

```
sudo php -d detect_unicode=0 go-pear.phar
```

In the install there are options to change directories pear is using. They were already set to the correct locations for my new php such as /usr/local/php5/bin

I then had to add that path to my bash_profile for the pear command to be recognised.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/php5/bin
```

To get pecl working again I removed pecl from /usr/bin then symlinked to the pecl in /usr/local/php5/bin

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/php5/bin/pecl /usr/bin/pecl
```

The first package I tried to install was APC and I got the error

```
Cannot find autoconf. Please check your autoconf installation and the
$PHP_AUTOCONF environment variable. Then, rerun this script.

ERROR: `phpize' failed
```

This was sorted by following instructions from [phpize won't work on Mac OS X Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430977/phpize-wont-work-on-mac-os-x-lion) I used the homebrew solution

UPDATE: I installed PHPUnit fine then ran `phpunit --version`

This gave an error of

```
PHP Warning:  require(/usr/lib/php/pear/PHPUnit/Autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/bin/phpunit on line 43
```

Running `which phpunit` returned `/usr/bin/phpunit`

Solved by more symlinking

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/php5/bin/phpunit phpunit
```

Answer (score 10):

On Mavericks there's a file in `/usr/lib/php` called `install-pear-nozlib.phar`

Everything worked by just running
`sudo php install-pear-nozlib.phar` from that directory. And then adding `/usr/lib/php/pear` to the include path in php.ini

Hope that helps someone

Answer (score 2):

I have this issue with one of my users on my Mac. It works fine with the other. So I guess it could have something to do with installing pear using the other user (as that's what I did).

I have no solution to this, but you could try to install pear again and try to select to install it to system instead of local and see if that works.

Edit: I tried to do this, however pear started to work, but not pecl.